# Duplication while appending the rows in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I am new to jquery and javascript.please help me to resolve this error. When clicking the checkbox(more than 3 times) it append the cells more than one time. Thanks in advance. Please help me.   * its appending the cells more than once

```js
function suma()
{ 
alert("hi");
$('#one').on("click", function(){
        $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
        $("#two tr").append("<td> a </td>","<td> b</td>","<td> c</td>");
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="suma()"/> 

<table id="one" border="1">
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>1</td>
<td> 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 3</td>
<td> 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 5</td>
<td> 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>7</td>
<td> 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="two" border="1">
<th> msg1</th>
<th> msg2</th>
<th> msg3</th>
<th> msg4</th>
<th> msg5</th>
<th> msg6</th>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you use jQuery 1.3.1 ?

Comment: Is this a working example? the one you have posted.?

Comment: tell us clearly what you are looking or expected answer?

Comment: No specific reason@Gerard

Comment: Yeah that button was working in my file. I dint why its not working in stackoverflow editor.@lalithkumar

Comment: when you check the checkbox you want to append the row in the table?

Comment: @lalithkumarwhen you click the checkbox in (table 1) and submit button. *that row should be added to second table + with additional cells.

Comment: the problem is table is not clicked, 
 `$('#one tr').on` try this

Comment: see you dont have tr in  `#two`

Comment: and try use .live , it works for old version . and your code will work

Comment: share the output Raghavi, how output should exactly look like...

Comment: @Raghavi i think You need to click on check then its display on bottom table if uncheck at that need to remove from bottom Am i Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function suma() {
  $('#one').on("click", function() {
    var appendStr = "<td> a </td><td> b</td><td> c</td>";
    $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().wrap("<tr></tr>")
                                        .append(appendStr).appendTo("#two");
    // add string inside TR and append the a b c then appendTo table.
  });
}
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zawwom8d/1/)

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why you are having your jquery click event inside function.

Replace your function with this :

```
function suma(){ 
    $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
    $("#two tr").append("<td> a </td>","<td> b</td>","<td> c</td>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the div(#two) already don't have the table("#one") then add it with find function then check if the table does not have this tr then add it be carful that you add table depending on if which will result in more than one with the same id so depend on class is prefer.

```
 function suma()
{ 
alert("hi");
$('#one').on("click", function(){
if($("#two").find("#one")==0){
    $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
}
if($("#two").find("#one").find("<tr><td> a </td>","<td> b</td>","<td> c</td></tr>") ==0){
    $("#two").find("#one").append("<tr><td> a </td>","<td> b</td>","<td> c</td></tr>");
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append additional text, then after need to append to #two
Try following code,

```js
function suma()
{

 var row = $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().append("<td> a </td><td> b</td><td> c</td>");
 
 row.appendTo("#two");
        

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="suma()"/> 

<table id="one" border="1">
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>1</td>
<td> 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 3</td>
<td> 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 5</td>
<td> 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>7</td>
<td> 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="two" border="1">
<th> msg1</th>
<th> msg2</th>
<th> msg3</th>
<th> msg4</th>
<th> msg5</th>
<th> msg6</th>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You are Looking For this.

```js
$('#one').on("click", function(){
        $('#one input:checked').parent().parent().appendTo("#two");
        $("#two tr").append("<td> a </td>","<td> b</td>","<td> c</td>");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="suma()"/> 

<table id="one" border="1">
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>1</td>
<td> 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 3</td>
<td> 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td> 5</td>
<td> 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>7</td>
<td> 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>9</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
</tr>

</table>
<table id="two" border="1">
<th> msg1</th>
<th> msg2</th>
<th> msg3</th>
   
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: @Raghavi See As per your image its Works Just set your jquery 1.3.1 to Jquery 2.1.1